# Reference a header-arg :var from within a header argument?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

As the title states, is it possible to reference header argument variables in the value part of other header arguments? Something along the lines of

```
#+PROPERTY: header-args :var session-name="The name of the session"

#+begin_src bash :session (org-get-header-var "session-name")
in_process_storage=5
#+end_src

#+begin_src bash :session (org-sbe "session-name")
echo $in_process_storage
#+end_src
#+RESULTS:
: 5
```

**Example using a named code block**

I know it is possible to reference named tables or the result of named code blocks like follows. Note that this example is only included to explain the effect I want to achieve.

```
#+name: session-name
#+begin_src elisp :results value raw
"The name of a session"
#+end_src
#+RESULTS: session-name
The name of a session

#+begin_src bash :session (org-sbe "session-name")
in_process_storage=5
#+end_src

#+begin_src bash :session (org-sbe "session-name")
echo $in_process_storage
#+end_src
#+RESULTS:
: 5
```

We will also see the output in the buffer named `The name of a session`, which we can switch to with `C-x b`.